How to add AWS Package inside CustomFramework?
I want to add FaceLiveness Package through this Url -- through this Url https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui-swift-liveness.git , I tried to use multiple ways for adding this package, but we are getting issue like some files not supporting issue and others,enter image description here
How to Add this package inside framework for using their FaceLiveness features ?

How will people be installing your framework ? By the looks of your image, it seems like cocoapods. If that is the case, you could add that FaceLiveness Package as a dependancy in your framework's podspec.
